# How do I connect from an XPCOM object to a GStreamer plugin in a Songbird addon?

Tags: c++, xpcom, gstreamer, songbird

I am writing a Songbird addon, with three parts: XUL (javascript), a GStreamer filter and an XPCOM addon.

I am interested in accessing the GStreamer layer from my XPCOM component. If anyone knows any resources on how to do that I'd be grateful.

Specifically, I need documentation or examples on accessing the GStreamer functionality from within my addon (building a GST pipeline and running a file through it, from my XPCOM component (C++).

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few months ago I created a XULRunner application for recording live camera and audio streams. It was based on GStreamer via an XPCOM component. I got my inspiration from the [GStreamer code](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=nl#OGomNmoy7MM/trunk/client/components/mediacore/gstreamer/src/sbGStreamerMediacore.cpp&q=sbGStreamerMediacore::SetVideoWindow&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc&l=1440).

However, you want to access the GStreamer functionality from Songbird. I'm not familiar with that route. If I were you I would start with looking at the [addons-api documentation](http://developer.songbirdnest.com/add-on-api/docs/trunk/).

If StackOverflow isn't very responsive you can always try the [songbird-dev](http://groups.google.com/group/songbird-dev) mailing list, or the irc channel: [irc://irc.mozilla.org/#songbird](http://irc://irc.mozilla.org/#songbird).

HTH